# Getting an ANN to learn to recognise an advantageous state in a game of draughts?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

As homework for university, we were given the task of creating a simple AI that could play a game of draughts using a minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning. What other techniques we used were up to us.

In our group, we decided to use an artificial neural network as the evaluation function (mostly for fun), such that, over time, it would learn to recognize board states that are good or bad for the AI. This indeed implies that we're noobs when it comes to AI.

It's a fairly simple feed-forward neural net with 50 input neurons (for 50 squares of the board), 25 hidden neurons in a single layer, and 1 output neuron.

Output varies between -1 and 1, with a higher value designating a state that was advantageous for the player, and a lower one being bad. It uses `tanh` as an activation function.

We used the back-propagation algorithm to make it learn.

Repeatedly presenting it with a set of inputs and desired outputs, it actually learned the patterns quite well!

We first put it through some initial training, where we generated random board states, and set the target value to be the ratio of "your" pieces to "opponent" pieces, always restricted to [-1,1]. The ANN appeared to also pick up this pattern quite well.

However, we also wanted it to learn from experience, where we could make it play a few hundred games, and have it learn from that. So, first, we put it through the "initial training", and then, after each game, in pseudocode, we did this:

```
learnRate = 0.05;
if ( the game was won ) {
    desireability_adjust = 0.1f;
} else {
    desireability_adjust = -0.1f;
}

foreach boardState in (board states recorded during play in reverse order) {

    currentOutput = neuralnet.evaluate(boardState)

    targetOutput = currentOutput + desireability_adjust * (1 - abs(currentOutput))

    neuralnet.learn(boardState, targetOuput, learnRate)

    // Decrease the desireability_adjust for every step
    desireability_adjust *= 0.9; 
}
```

This gave very mixed results. The "experienced" players regularly lost against those who just got out of initial training, and the classic minimax player that simply counted pieces simply slaughtered the NN-driven ones.

What changes to this approach would you advise get the NN to learn the game? Would making the network bigger or deeper do anything? Is there something obviously bad about the post-game learning algorithm?

**EDIT:**

I changed the post-game algorithm to this, instead of the "adjustment" method proposed above:

```
learnRate = 0.1f;

if (win) {
    resultValue = 0.95 // Not 1 because tanh cannot reach 1 or -1
} else {
    resultValue = -0.95
}

// 0-based index is assumed
recordedstates = (list of states recorded during the game, in order)

for (index from recordedstates.length - 1 to 0) { {

    t = (index / recordedstates.length - 1);

    targetOutput = t * resultValue;

    nn.learn(recordedstates[index], targetOutput, learnRate)
}
```

The intuition is that the target value represents a "progress to the result", where a value of near 0 means the game is near the initial state, and -0.95 and 0.95 mean being close to either a loss or a win, respectively.

The homework is mostly about minimax with alpha-beta anyway, and we're going to have a competition to see who made the best AI. We're probably going to lose badly, but it will probably yield a large number of very strong opponent players to train with. Neural nets fascinate me, so I'll probably keep working on it.

What I also noticed was that some networks that lost often became "depressed", where they would report just about any state as being negative. Hopefully the new learning method above will tend to do that a lot less.

**EDIT:2** I also added a few unit test cases. Most notably this one:

```
int[] hitPositionNearWin = {0,
              EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
        EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
              EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
        EMPTY,      EMPTY,      BLACKPIECE, EMPTY,      EMPTY,
              EMPTY,      EMPTY,      WHITEPIECE, EMPTY,      EMPTY,
        EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
              EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
        EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
              EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
        EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,      EMPTY,
    };
```

What I expect is that the neural net returns 1 from both the black and the white player's perspective, because the board is always evaluated from the perspective of the player who is about to make a move, and whoever gets to make a move here wins.

At the moment, the neural net gives:

- One-hit win for white: -0.04490412 (Expected near 1)
- One-hit win for black: 0.08066118 (Also expected near 1)

Is it correct that a 3-layer net (1 hidden, 1 input, 1 output) should be able to recognize such a situation? (Regardless of where it occurs on the board.)

Having only a single piece left gives scores closer to the extremes, as that is a winning position, which is correct.

Comment: About your EDIT2: Yes, A three layer neural network should be able to learn this. However, I do agree with you that position you feed in should be close to either -1 or 1 depending on the viewpoint. As I understand draughts, there is only one move left. I think there must be a bug somewhere. Can you share the code? Say github or something?

Comment: It should always be 1, because the neural net is supposed to always look at the board as if it is about to make a move. This situation would thus always be a win from either perspective, since the only possible move is to remove the opponent piece. Ok, I'll try my best to make the code a bit more readable and upload it somewhere. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/werner291/2e2b5d8ba6c76128c78a

Comment: I've included the Minimax leaf evaluation, the training code, and the state to input translation code.

Comment: Did you see my comments on github?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like a task do a reinforcement learning technique. Take a look at temporal difference learning. Look at the TD-gammon articles by Tesauro. Just note that you probably need exploration nodes while training. (Backgammon does not need exploration since it get variation from dice rolls.)

For the best introduction to Reinforcement Learning you should read [Sutton and Barto](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html).

**Edit:** I think you can do learning by doing the training forward (insted of the backward process you suggest). Let me elaborate with some (C-inspired) pseudo code:

```
/* First initialize your neural net with random weights */
for( int i = 0; i < N_TRAINING_GAMES; i++ ){
    board b = board_of_initial_state;
    do {
        movelist ml = find_all_legal_moves( b );
        /* evaluate and score each move in the list of legal moves */
        for(each move m in ml){
             board b_tmp = do_move( b, m );
             if (b_tmp == won_game_state)
                 m.score = +1.0;
             else if (b_tmp == lost_game_state)
                 m.score = -1.0;
             else
                 m.score = neuralnet_forward_calculate( b_tmp );
        }            
        move m = pick_a_move_for_movelist( ml ); /* do not be greedy all time. Maybe use softmax. See Sutton & Barto Ch. 2 */
        neuralnet_backpropagation( b, m.score ); 
        b = do_move( b, m );  /* Update the board state */
    } while( game_is_not_over( b ) ); 
}
```

I have not tested this code on draughts, but I do guess it will converge after a couple of thousands of games. Please tell me how you progress, as this is really interesting to me.

**Another edit:** I have specified some details in the code. Hopefully it is clear. So in each training game:

- You evaluate the board state after each legal move.
- Then you pick one of the moves -- the best scored move by highest probability. (use softmax to pick).
- Then you do a backpropagation on the neural net
  with the *original* board state as the pattern, and *next* board
  state's score. (I think you have to multipy by -1 since it is from
  the other players point of view.)
- Update the board with the move you picked.

The above code is what I consider a TD(0) algorithm. (If some reinforcement learning gurus disagree with me, please tell me.) It is a game specific implementation of the algorithms you find in [Sutton & Barto Ch.6](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node61.html). However the lingo is a bit more general in the book. An **state** in the book is typically a board position in a game. An **action** in the book is usually move on the game board.

The above code still is pseudo code, at lot of things are still missing. You should of course have a way to benchmark the strength of you agent, such that you know when it does not improve anymore. When you have done TD-training, your static neural net evaluator function can be used in a minimax search.

Comment: Hi! I'll have a look at TD-learning, and try the method you proposed. If I understand correctly, the method you're proposing actually has the neural net choosing which move to make? In my case, we're using a search algorithm, and the neural net to evaluate how "desirable" the board is to the player.

Comment: Oh... wait a second... so you're not actually using some game framework with an opponent, but you're simulating the game yourself? This is an idea that I didn't think of... I'll try it after the assignement deadline and report with results.

Comment: You should evaluate the board state after **all** legal moves with the current neural net, yes. But if you then always pick the best move, the algorithm will **not** converge. If you always do the best move from the evaluator, you will just replay the same game over and over again. Please look at [2.3 Softmax Action Selection](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node17.html), and select the move from this formula. Or something similar. With highest probability you should pick the best move. Then with some lower probability you should pick the second best move... so on...

Comment: Yes! Everything will be self-play by the machine, such that the agent will learn all by it self. No need for human interaction.

Comment: I'll check out softmax. I thought I was restricted to minimax for selecting the move, but I guess not when simulating the game. The teacher said it wouldn't be a problem to provide me with the other players. I already had a framework, but it was written in a very rigid way, not good enough for training.

Comment: Yes! You really don't need any minimax while training. The training algorithm in my answer is really for getting an evaluating function. Just start off with random weights in your neural net, and then implement an evaluation for a the leaf nodes, (ie evaluate board position at game over state.) That's all you need.

Comment: At one moment, you call "target=score_of_board_after_move(m)" before the end of the game. What kind of function would that be? Personally, I suck at draughts, and the computer needs to learn what's a good move, I can't teach it. Could that be something like the post-game training algorithm I added below the "EDIT:", or is it something better?

Comment: Ah, so basically the the win/lose scores sort of propagate backward from the end of the game to the start? That's an interesting thing I didn't think of. I've got a lot of Internet-less downtime coming up, so I'll implement it soon.

Comment: Please update me when you're getting on. This is really interesting to me as well.

Comment: Well, just implemented it. Initial results are **very** promising. It just slaughtered the Optimist player (which always plays the first move in the movelist.) I'll try against piece-counting Minimax when I get a chance to plug in my laptop.

Comment: Aaaand now it's apparently trying to give away as many pieces as possible. But this is probably a problem with my implementation....

Comment: Remember to flip the score when you select a move. You evaluate the position after each move is done. In other works: you select the worst move from your opponents viewpoint. That is your best move.

Comment: Hmmm... it now appears to be able to match the MiniMax player that counts pieces with 5000 iterations of training in certain situations. It also gives everything away in other situations. It's probably a missing NOT operator somewhere, but we're getting somewhere!

Comment: 5000 training games.... I don't think that is enough. I was guessing in my mind, based on my experience from backgammon and the complexity of draughts, that you will meed a couple of hundred thousand games. Leave the training over night, and see how it develops. (This is where a benchmark comes convenient. I you have a benchmark you can run your network through, you know when to stop the training.)

Comment: Discovered an error in the serialization/deserialisation that caused some problems, that's solved now. "a couple hundred thousand games"? Okay... What kind of learning rates and network sizes do you recommend? I currently have 50 inputs, 2 hidden layers of 50 neurons each, 1 output, and a learn rate of 0.1. It plays quite decently after 50000 iterations (though I know it has the potential to beat the current opponent quite easily....), but I'll give it 50000 iterations with 0.05 learnrate, see where that brings me.

Comment: 500000 iterations later... it's not clearly improved over the <10000 iteration-trained networks. I'm trying it again with a single hidden layer and have a look through my code to see if I missed something.